# HTML image is not changing

Tags: javascript

i am creating a small game in which i need to change a image on click event but 
i am not able to change the image

i have tried querySelector to change the HTML  element

```
document.querySelector(".rolling").addEventListener('click',function()
{

// 1.Random Number
dice=Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);

// 2.Display the Result
var diceDOM=document.querySelector('.dice');
diceDOM.style.display="block";
diceDOM.src="../images/"+dice+".jpg";


//3.Update the roundScore

});
```

Comment: Show us your whole code or post the images , Without all this it will be hard to help you out

Comment: post [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that we can help you identify the problem.

Comment: Maybe `dice=Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;` instead of 
`dice=Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1)`;

Comment: As shown your code should work correctly. We'll need to see the HTML, or possibly an explanation of what you mean by "not able to change the image" -- is it not changing at all? Or is it changing to the wrong thing, or a broken image (indicating that you've got the URL wrong)? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to put your script just before closing body tag in case DOM manipulation scripting.
because before body load script try to find element with queryselector so it returns null

see this

```
document.querySelector(".rolling").addEventListener('click',function()
{

// 1.Random Number
dice=Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);

/*  change querySelectorAll to queryselector if you want to use all you have to iterate loop  */
var diceDOM=document.querySelector('.dice');
diceDOM.style.display="block";
diceDOM.src="../images/"+dice+".jpg";


//3.Update the roundScore

});

});
```

i hope this will help you